# Setting function parameter dynamically

Tags: javascript, function

Hello I do have following code sample in which Im trying to give each element different onClick functionality :

```
for (var i = 0; i < sizex; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < sizey; j++) {
            var canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
            var id = i * 10 + j;
            canvas.id = "canvas" + id;
            canvas.width = 25;
            canvas.height = 25;
            canvas.style = "border:1px solid black";
            canvas.onclick = function() {
               canvasClicked(id);
            };

            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        }
    }
```

problem is its always called with id = sizex * 10 + sizey

who can I pass parameter of canvasCliced to function so this function is "different" for each canvas?

Comment: Closures my friend, learn them, love them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a closure.

Change your click handler from

```
canvas.onclick = function() {
     canvasClicked(id);
};
```

to form a **closure**, where in the scope of the variable would be accessible.

```
canvas.onclick = function(nId) {
    return function() {
       canvasClicked(nId);
    }
}(id);
```